# LSM9DS0 driver for MSP430

Tags: driver, msp430

I am working on a project to interface LSM9DS0 with a MSP430.
Looking for a driver in C / C++ that I can use as a reference design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this [sample code](https://github.com/mykiimike/miniPhi/blob/master/drivers/sensors/LSM9DS0.c) and project will help you out a little

It's part of a larger project based on the MSP430 so don't expect to be able to drag and drop it, but it may help you figure out how to initialize and read values from the device.

Answer (score 2):

A Google search provides [these design files](https://github.com/sparkfun/LSM9DS0_Breakout) for a breakout board, and the C++ files for interfacing it with an Arduino. Also some [from Adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_LSM9DS0_Library).

Good enough for a reference while writing your own drivers.

Comment: This is what I would go with. Sparkfun's libraries are very well documented, and easy to port over to different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Driver? I thought only Windows used drivers these days...

It's an I2C device. Read the datasheet, get the I2C commands, and use the standard I2C functions your system's libraries provide.

Comment: Linux drivers..?  I've noticed the MCU vendors are starting to talk more and more about "drivers" when referring to simple hardware abstraction layers for say I2C.  Then pushing their solutions as a way to differentiate themselves.   It makes it sound complicated and scary.

Comment: Linux kernel modules :P  And I can't remember the last time I had to install one to get some hardware working - it just works.